# How to get Chrome in foreground?

Tags: c#, google-chrome

In c#
I'm trying to get a button to start Chrome if its not running and set it in the foreground when it is already running.
However, the first part is working but the second (foreground part) is not.

```
        private void Chrome_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process[] pname = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");
        if (pname.Length == 0)
        {
             Process notePad = new Process();
             notePad.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.EXE";
             notePad.Start();
            notePad.Refresh();
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                Process[] prcssArray = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");
                if (prcssArray.Length > 0)
                    SetForegroundWindow(prcssArray[0].Handle);
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: How is `SetForegroundWindow` defined?  Does the Chrome process meet the requirements defined in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setforegroundwindow#remarks)?  Also, an empty `catch` block is going to swallow all exceptions, which is not helpful when asking "Why doesn't this work?"

Comment: You may take a look at https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/16428/how-can-i-bring-chrome-browser-to-focus-when-running-a-selenium-test-using-chrom

Comment: BACON i guess its not in the list, so what is the right way?